# std::optional<std::size_t> correct values comparison

Tags: c++, optional

I need to compare two `std::optional<std::size_t>` variables, considering all possible cases(both `std::nullopt` or one of them exists of both exist).

I try to achieve the most compact version of it, but it looks ugly to me.

The code below is executed within a loop and I need to detect the higher priority of an element.

```
std::optional<std::size_t> idx_1 = ...; // nullopt or some value
std::optional<std::size_t> idx_2 = ...; // nullopt or some value

const bool idx_1_initial_priority = idx_1 && !idx_2;
const bool idx_1_priority_higher = idx_1_initial_priority ? true : idx_1 && idx_2? *idx_1 < *idx_2 : false;
```

I need to check - whether `idx_1` has a higher priority(lower value) over `idx_2`.

How can it be simplified? Maybe using `value_or()`, but using zero will break the whole logic because 0 is the higher priority at all.

Comment: Code Review is quite different from Stack Overflow, we want to see more of the code rather than the minimal code to reproduce the problem. At a minimum we need to see complete functions, although complete classes or complete solutions is better. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Comment: What's wrong with `value_or(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())`?

Comment: @TobySpeight Cool, that's what I need:
`idx_1_initial_priority.value_or(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()) < idx_2_initial_priority.value_or(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())`

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, it appears that you could write this as a nested ternary expression:

```cpp
const bool priority_higher = !idx_1 ? false
                           : idx_2  ? *idx_1 < *idx_2
                           :          true; // idx_1 && !idx_2.
```

You could also turn this into a phi function, maybe something like `constexpr bool is_lower_priority(std::optional<std::size_t>, std::optional<std::size_t>)`, and use an if-else structure within that.

Comment: When you yield boolean literals from a ternary like that, it's usually a sign the expression can be simplified (probably to `idx_1 && (!idx_2 || *idx_1 < *idx_2)`, though I don't have the unit tests to prove it).

Comment: @TobySpeight That works too.